# Using a Java enum as a Maven mojo property

Tags: java, enums, maven-plugin

I'm building a custom Maven plugin and would like one of the configuration parameters of the mojo to be driven by a Java enum.  I've searched all over the web and cannot seem to find any indication of how/whether this is possible, short of references to an "MNG-4292" ticket ([ref](https://issues.maven.apache.narkive.com/6ycxGZQo/jira-created-mng-4292-support-enum-type-parameters-in-mojos)) which seem to imply it is possible but the links are dead.

I tried creating an enum

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    NONE,
    DIRECT,
    INCREMENT
}
```

and then using it on a `@Parameter` annotation

```java
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * My Mojo.
 */
@Mojo(name = "sync", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_RESOURCES, threadSafe = true)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  @Parameter(defaultValue = MyEnum.DIRECT)
  private MyEnum pickOne;

  ...
}
```

However, I get IDE errors like:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyEnum to String

Can anyone explain how/if you can use a Java enum on a Maven mojo parameter?

Comment: I was finally able to find https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4292 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5861.  MNG-5861 comment says "Enums are supported, see the Enum section here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html" but that page does not appear to have any such section.  So confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute `defaultValue` of `@Parameter` annotation is a `String` type.

All plugins parameter in pom.xml and/or in command line are provided as String, so `defaultValue` is also a String type.
Maven convert parameters from String to destination type in runtime.
Here is list of common converters: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Parameters

For annotation attribute you must provide a constant value, so in your case it must be:

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue = "DIRECT")
```

For Enums Maven will use `Enum.valueOf(String)` for convert this value in runtime.

---

ASF project JIRA has address: https://issues.apache.org/
Correct address for mentioned issues is: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4292

Comment: It is weird that the ticket was closed with fixed status in 2009. But still having this in 2024...